# QSocketnotifier does not work on windows for serialport reading?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am developing an application which reads data from the device (Microcontroller) connected on SerialPort of Windows 7 and display all read data into the Qt based UI application.

Environment:
Qt: Qt 5.6.0
OS: Windows 7

Before implementing the continious reading from the Windows Serial port. I implemented a test application to read data from Serial port on button press (Some button in Qt GUI) using QSerialPort Class and it worked properly.

So I started implementing the continious reading from the device connected at serial port example:
1. Connect PushButton Press. Connect to the Device.
2. Start Push Button Press. Start Reading.
3. Stop Push Button Press. Stop Reading.

Here my code is same as like my test application but for continious reading. I implemented the QSocketNotifier functionality when I connect to the Device (Connect Push Button press). Below is the code for the same:

```
bool Test::openPort()
{
    bool result = false;

    //SerialPortManager: Class to Open, Read, Write to the device connected at Serial Port
    if(serialPortManager != NULL) 
    {
        result = serialPortManager->open(); // Returns TRUE

        if(operationSuccessful)
        {
            //socketNotifier  pointer defined in TestClass.h file
        socketNotifier = new QSocketNotifier(serialPortManager->getSerialPortFileDescriptor(), QSocketNotifier::Read);
            connect(socketNotifier , SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(onReadData()));

        socketNotifier ->setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    return result ;
}

qint32 SerialPortManager::getSerialPortFileDescriptor()
{
    int readFileDescriptor = _open_osfhandle((qintptr)serialPort.handle(), _O_RDONLY | _O_WRONLY);

    return readFileDescriptor;
    //return (qintptr)serialPort.handle();
}
```

where QSerialPort serialPort; is public variable defined in Class Header File.

Here Problem is SLOT onReadData() which is connected to the SocketNotifier is never get called. It looks like to me that the activated(int) signal is never emitted.

I did some google and on one link I found that QSocketNotifier does not work for SerialPort reading on Windows. Since the link is very old So wanted to confirm.
http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2008-03/00128/Re-QSocketNotifier.html

Please advise what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: `socketNotifier = new QSocketNotifier(serialPortManager->getSerialPortFileDescriptor(), QSocketNotifier::Read,this);` in this code put parrent like that i put

Comment: Hello  H.Ghassami, Thanks for your reply. I added "this" parent but it didn't helped. Still SLOT onReadData() is not getting called.  Below is the code which I am using to get the file descriptor hope it helps in solving issue:              .                                                                                       qint32 SerialPortManager::getSerialPortFileDescriptor()
{
    int readFileDescriptor = _open_osfhandle((qintptr)serialPort.handle(), _O_RDONLY | _O_WRONLY);

    return readFileDescriptor;
    //return (qintptr)serialPort.handle();
}

Comment: I do the same as you with socket programing in qt. At first I make a config for connecting to socket in a class. then in main window open the socket and set the socket notifier . `serialport->openport();notifier=new QSocketNotifier(serialport->fd, QSocketNotifier::Read,this); notifier->setEnabled(true);Connect(this->notifier,SIGNAL(activated(int)),this,SLOT(ReadAndProcessData()));` and also after the slot is runnig you should enable the notifier again.

Comment: Hello H.Ghassami. I am not able to understand point "config for connecting to socket"?? My application is having  one class "SerialPortManager" which includes QSerialPort class. This class I am using to Open Serial port for the device. Port is openend successfully. Now in another class called Test derived from QOBject (MainWindow is another class) I am creating a socketNotifier and connecting it to the SLOT which is not working. Here can you please explain what is the config which you are mentioning? Can you share the sample with me  for Windows? Thanks in Advance,

Comment: your port is open successfully? yes? and you call socket notifier in another class? mixed them in one class.the port opening and socket notifier.

Comment: Hello H.Ghassami, I modified the code as per your suggestions i.e. First Open the port.->If port is openend successfully->created the socket notifier in functionA (In this function again checked if the port is openend) -> Connected the socketNotifier activated(int) signal to the slot in function A. I have done all this in one class but still that slot is not getting called.

Comment: Thanks Hello H.Ghassami for helping me in understanding SocketNotifier more better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `QSocketNotifier` with serial ports in Qt.

`QSerialPort` inherits from `QIODevice`, so you can connect its signal `readyRead()` to your slot `onReadData`.

On Windows, `QSocketNotifier` seems to only work with sockets, because it uses a WinSock2 function internally. For other Window handles, you could use `QWinEventNotifier` (`QSerialPort` has a similar private class `QWinOverlappedIoNotifier`).