# Is QSerialPort event based implemented?

Tags: c++, qt, pyside6, pyqt6

This question concerns the QSerialPort Library from Qt, but has actually arisen from PySide6 in Python, hence I tagged both.

According to the QSerialPort Documentation, it is possible to have a signal emitted every time new data is available on e.g. the serial port:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#readyRead

Since I did not find any event based serial port library for C++ (or python), I'm quite sceptical if they are using an event based approach for emitting the signal or rather internally polling until data is available.

I already checked out the documentation and internet and source code, but I could only find the readNotification function for the Unix-Implementation in qiodevice.cpp, which emits the readyRead signal. However, I could not find in which context the function is called, so it's still unclear for me.

According to this answer for a "readyRad-Question" it looks like Qt is using internally the API of the OS (but still supposition).

[QSocketnotifier does not work on windows for serialport reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327570/qsocketnotifier-does-not-work-on-windows-for-serialport-reading)

Comment: I/O events are platform-specific.  Major OSes like Windows, Linux, BSD are definitely capable of generating events for serial port transfers.  (This is not answering your question about whether Qt is using them, just that the underlying foundation exists in the OS)

Comment: Well, they do use poll https://github.com/qt/qtserialport/blob/2180e6ac44c2f48d6a4de17115938411923506ee/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp#L995